# Inner Nested Static Class cannot be called from another class

Tags: java, android

I have one class in a file named WeatherContract.java which has a static inner class, as follows:

```
public class WeatherContract {
...
...
    public static final class WeatherEntry implements BaseColumns {
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to call the inner class in another file called TestWeatherContract.java as follows

```
...
import com.example.android.sunshine.app.data.WeatherContract;
...

public class TestWeatherContract extends AndroidTestCase {
...
    public void testBuildWeatherLocation() {
        Uri locationUri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocation(TEST_WEATHER_LOCATION);
...
```

Now in the following line, the word "WeatherEntry" is marked in red and when I hover on the word I get the following error "Cannot resolve symbol 'WeatherEntry'.

```
Uri locationUri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocation(TEST_WEATHER_LOCATION);
```

Please note that I am not getting any error in the import statement, so I'm assuming that there are no errors in stating the path of the class.

Also, I have another file called FetchWeatherTask.java. I have the following import statement at the beginning of the file:

```
import com.example.android.sunshine.app.data.WeatherContract.WeatherEntry;
```

In this case, in the import statement again the word "WeatherEntry" is marked in red and I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'WeatherEntry'".

Please help. I'm on Android Studio 1.5. I have posted this question earlier, but it was put on hold because I provided incomplete details. So I am posting it again with all details. I'm sorry if I have violated the rules of the community, I am new here. Thank you.

Comment: remove final from WeatherEntry and check

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

`WeatherEntry` is a class and not a member. To access methods of `WeatherEntry` you still need an instance of it. E.g.

```
WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocation(TEST_WEATHER_LOCATION);
```

should be

```
WeatherEntry weatherEntry = new WeatherContract.WeatherEntry();
weatherEntry.buildWeatherLocation(TEST_WEATHER_LOCATION);
```

Comment: except if buildWeatherLocation is a static method